# port networkx graph to graphviz without pygraphviz

Tags: networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am working in Python 3 on a windows machine and despite many efforts have not been able to get pygraphviz installed. Separate discussion.

I have networkx and graphviz modules...**Is there a paradigm for building network graphs in networkx and extracting to a graphviz format for display that does not use pygraphviz?**

It seems all the relevant functionality in drawing.nx_agraph and nx_agraph requires pygraphviz but I have gotten accustomed to using networkx and like the functionality therein. In the documentation for networkx it even says they are focusing on the development of graph objects and not on the actual display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pydot (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot) as a pure Python alternative to PyGraphviz

```
In [1]: import networkx

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: G = networkx.path_graph(4)

In [4]: networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(G,sys.stdout)
strict graph  {
0;
1;
2;
3;
0 -- 1;
1 -- 2;
2 -- 3;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for the same thing: How to get dot notation from a graph in [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/)?

(If you are only interested in the answer, skip this paragraph. I actually wanted to display a NetworkX multigraph, but even though [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) is powerful python library for manipulation of networks and graphs, it has fairly limited options when it comes displaying (rendering) graphs and networks. [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) uses [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) to provide basic functionality for visualizing graphs, which doesn't have the option for visualizing multigraph. [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) is not intended for visualizing graphs so in [NetworkX documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) they recommend using some of graph visualization tools, [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/), [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). All of this tools have some kind of python interfaces but the best one (easiest and simplest to use) is [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) which supports the DOT language of the [Graphviz drawing software](http://www.graphviz.org/). Visualizing graphs in [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) is very simple and convenient, you can use one short line such as `graph.view()` which by default creates a PDF file and opens it in your system's default PDF viewer, but you can also view and create image files such as SVG and PNG. So it would be ideal to convert NetworkX graph to graphviz graph and to do that you need to convert NetworkX graph to DOT notation which can then be read by [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz).)

Solution by Aric is simple and works for printing out DOT notation of graph, but is kind of a hack and also in my case, I need to save DOT notation in string variable so I can use it to create a graph in [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) from that DOT notation.

`networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot`([source](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py#LC41)) is a function that creates DOT format and saves it to a path (file handle). Code of this function is:

```
@open_file(1, mode='w')
def write_dot(G, path):
    P = to_pydot(G)
    path.write(P.to_string())
    return
```

And this gives us the solution for answer:

```
from networkx import path_graph
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import to_pydot

G = path_graph(4)
dot = to_pydot(G).to_string()
print(dot)
```

Function `to_pydot` ([source](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py#LC174)) uses [pydot](https://github.com/pydot/pydot) library to create `pydot.Dot` object which has `to_string` ([source](https://github.com/pydot/pydot/blob/master/pydot.py#LC1471)) method that returns string representation of graph in DOT language.

P.S.:
To [render a DOT source code](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#using-raw-dot) in  [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) you can do something like this:

```
from graphviz import Source
src = Source(dot) # dot is string containing DOT notation of graph
src.view()
```

P.P.S.:
Two following pictures show difference when you use [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) (left side of image) and [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) (right side of image) to visualize graph `networkx.margulis_gabber_galil_graph(3)`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the color to the edge as a property and it will carry out into the file generated by write_dot()

> G.add_edge(src_node, dest_node, color="red")